# Java: non-heap-memory analyzes

Tags: java, memory-leaks, jvm

we have the problem that our non-heap-memory is growing all the time. so we have to restart our jee (java8) - webapp every 3rd day (as you can see in the screenshot here: [screenshot from non-heap- and heap-memory](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uhhte.png))

I have already tried to find out what fills up that non-heap. But I couldn't find any tool to create a nonheap-dump. do you have any idea how i could investigate on that to find out what elements are increasingly growing?

java-version

```
java version "1.8.0_102"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_102-b14)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 25.102-b14, mixed mode)
```

tomcat-version

```
Apache Tomcat Version 7.0.59
```

Comment: In a comment below you say that it's an embedded tomcat. Can you add to your post the JVM version and the parameters used to start it?

Comment: Also the version of tomcat is important

Comment: Thanks @Stefan if you have also the version of the embedded tomcat...

Comment: Since Tomcat version 7.0.59 some memory leak errors have been resolved. Can you upgrade it? Another way, if viable, could be to downgrade jvm to 1.7, verify if a perm space oom exists and in case analyze it with very mature tools (eclipse MAT, jmc, ...)

Answer (score 13):

Non-heap memory usage, as provided by [MemoryPoolMXBean](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/management/MemoryPoolMXBean.html) counts the following memory pools:

- Metaspace
- Compressed Class Space
- Code Cache

In other words, standard non-heap memory statistics includes spaces occupied by compiled methods and loaded classes. Most likely, the increasing non-heap memory usage indicates a class loader leak.

Use

- `jmap -clstats PID` to dump class loader statistics;
- `jcmd PID GC.class_stats` to print the detailed information about memory usage of each loaded class. The latter requires `-XX:+UnlockDiagnosticVMOptions`.

Answer (score 1):

As @apangin points out it looks like you are using more Metaspace over time.  This is usually means you are loading more classes. I would record which classes are being loaded and methods being compiled and try to limit how much this is being done in production on a continuous basis.  It is possible you have a library which is generating code continuously but not cleaning it up.  This is where looking at what classes are being created could give you a hint as to which one.

---

For native non-heap memory.

You can look at the memory mapping on Linux with `/proc/{pid}/maps`  This will let you know how much virtual memory is being used.

You need to determine whether this is due to

- increasing numbers of threads, or sockets
- direct ByteBuffers being used.
- a third party library which is using native / direct memory.

From looking at your graphs you could reduce your heap and increase your maximum direct memory and extend the restart time to a week or more, but a better solution would be solve the cause.

Comment: Looks like the OP's graphs show memory usage as provided by [MemoryPoolMXBean](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/management/MemoryPoolMXBean.html). None of the thread, socket, direct byte buffer or third-party libraries memory is included in standard non-heap statistics. Non-Heap pools are just Code Cache, Metaspace and Compressed Class Space. That's it.

Comment: That's an interesting observation. It would then point to a class loading problem (such a deploying a new .war or .ear file where the old version is not properly released, or excessive dynamic bytecode generation and loading, or a combination).

Comment: we run the j2ee-web-app with embedded tomcat, so no .war- or .ear-file-deployment

Answer (score 0):

With Java 8, class meta data is now in a non-heap memory section called *Metaspace* (and not in PermGen anymore). If your non-heap memory is mainly consumed by *Metaspace*, you can figure it out with [jstat](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/tools/unix/jstat.html).

It's not a general tool for analyzing non-heap memory. But it might still help in your case.