# Metaspace size keep increasing but heap size no change

Tags: java, garbage-collection, jvm, heap-memory, heap-dump

**What can I do to see which class cause metaspace increase**

My java application run on docker component, will restart due to memory insufficient. But heap of the application always same, just metaspace is increasing.

Here is the VM.native_memory on different time.

Early VM.native_memory

```
1:

Native Memory Tracking:

Total: reserved=11330400KB, committed=10175740KB
-                 Java Heap (reserved=8388608KB, committed=8388608KB)
                            (mmap: reserved=8388608KB, committed=8388608KB) 
 
-                     Class (reserved=1428418KB, committed=461222KB)
                            (classes #28562)
                            (malloc=23490KB #93321) 
                            (mmap: reserved=1404928KB, committed=437732KB) 
 
-                    Thread (reserved=773268KB, committed=773268KB)
                            (thread #750)
                            (stack: reserved=769912KB, committed=769912KB)
                            (malloc=2477KB #3756) 
                            (arena=879KB #1496)
 
-                      Code (reserved=262873KB, committed=75413KB)
                            (malloc=13273KB #18348) 
                            (mmap: reserved=249600KB, committed=62140KB) 
 
-                        GC (reserved=49323KB, committed=49323KB)
                            (malloc=20643KB #7192) 
                            (mmap: reserved=28680KB, committed=28680KB) 
 
-                  Compiler (reserved=2335KB, committed=2335KB)
                            (malloc=2204KB #3296) 
                            (arena=131KB #6)
 
-                  Internal (reserved=254106KB, committed=254102KB)
                            (malloc=254070KB #53117) 
                            (mmap: reserved=36KB, committed=32KB) 
 
-                    Symbol (reserved=30337KB, committed=30337KB)
                            (malloc=27995KB #290038) 
                            (arena=2342KB #1)
 
-    Native Memory Tracking (reserved=7985KB, committed=7985KB)
                            (malloc=518KB #7178) 
                            (tracking overhead=7466KB)
 
-               Arena Chunk (reserved=533KB, committed=533KB)
                            (malloc=533KB) 
 
-                   Unknown (reserved=132616KB, committed=132616KB)
                            (mmap: reserved=132616KB, committed=132616KB)
```

Later

```
1:

Native Memory Tracking:

Total: reserved=12291140KB, committed=11137844KB
-                 Java Heap (reserved=8388608KB, committed=8388608KB)
                            (mmap: reserved=8388608KB, committed=8388608KB) 
 
-                     Class (reserved=2339082KB, committed=1372142KB)
                            (classes #51312)
                            (malloc=37130KB #276495) 
                            (mmap: reserved=2301952KB, committed=1335012KB) 
 
-                    Thread (reserved=806307KB, committed=806307KB)
                            (thread #782)
                            (stack: reserved=802808KB, committed=802808KB)
                            (malloc=2583KB #3916) 
                            (arena=916KB #1560)
 
-                      Code (reserved=263192KB, committed=76840KB)
                            (malloc=13592KB #18702) 
                            (mmap: reserved=249600KB, committed=63248KB) 
 
-                        GC (reserved=50033KB, committed=50033KB)
                            (malloc=21353KB #29939) 
                            (mmap: reserved=28680KB, committed=28680KB) 
 
-                  Compiler (reserved=2344KB, committed=2344KB)
                            (malloc=2213KB #3299) 
                            (arena=131KB #6)
 
-                  Internal (reserved=263153KB, committed=263149KB)
                            (malloc=263117KB #99227) 
                            (mmap: reserved=36KB, committed=32KB) 
 
-                    Symbol (reserved=30338KB, committed=30338KB)
                            (malloc=27996KB #290067) 
                            (arena=2342KB #1)
 
-    Native Memory Tracking (reserved=12152KB, committed=12152KB)
                            (malloc=696KB #9776) 
                            (tracking overhead=11456KB)
 
-               Arena Chunk (reserved=3316KB, committed=3316KB)
                            (malloc=3316KB) 
 
-                   Unknown (reserved=132616KB, committed=132616KB)
                            (mmap: reserved=132616KB, committed=132616KB)
```

I see class num increase a lot, but I don't know what class cause increase.

Here is Application Monitor,I can't put this picture in this floor.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/CwZyy.jpg

Comment: *I don't know what class cause increase.* - We can't tell you what class caused it either.  But these resources may help you work it out:  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39329455 , https://www.infoq.com/articles/Troubleshooting-Java-Memory-Issues/ , https://www.baeldung.com/native-memory-tracking-in-jvm

Comment: In your first dump, there are 28562 loaded classes, in the second there are 51312 classes. I’d say, that’s a significant difference and a reason for having different metaspace sizes.

Comment: @Holger I see the difference of classes num, and I want to know what classes cause the difference. I try "jcmd GC.class_stats" but can't found reason. Is there any command can print all loaded class?

Comment: what I usually do is take heap dumps with the native memory tracking. Then open those in MAT memory analyzer and see the class loading information.