# Why is the number of threads in a java process different from the actual size of non-heap memory?

Tags: java, linux, jvm, centos7

The sentences may be strange due to my lack of English knowledge
Thanks to everyone who reads the question.

Hello?

I am running a java process on Centos7 and monitoring it with jconsole, but the number of threads currently created is different in non-heap memory size.

I know that one thread occupies 1mb by default, but even if 100thread is created, the size of non-heap memory is not 100mb. Why?

Comment: Thread stacks are not the only thing that lives in non-heap memory. So the values being "different" is not suprising. Are they higher or lower than what you expected?

Comment: Thank you for answer.

There are 200 threads, but the memory is about 100mb.

Less memory usage than expected.

Comment: So, can't the thread stack memory be checked as non-heap memory?

Do I need to infer thread stack memory by thread number?

Comment: memory is not allocated until it is needed

Comment: Sorry for frequently asking rudimentary questions.

Thank you so much for your kind replies.

So, when do you need thread stack memory?

Comment: when the stack causes a page fault

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Non-Heap memory](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39329455/java-non-heap-memory-analyzes), as shown by `jconsole`, includes Metaspace, Compressed Class Space and Code Cache. In other words, it counts memory used by loaded classes and compiled methods. It has nothing to do with threads and stacks.

Comment: I thought until now that non-heap memory contains the thread stack. But it doesn't.

Thanks for your reply.